# Domain in polar coordinates, extremes of integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, polar-coordinates

I have to calculate the double integral in a 'D' domain:
$$ D= \{x^2 + y^2 \le 1; x^2 +(y-1)^2 \ge 1 ; x^2 + (y+1)^2 \ge 1 \}$$

I want to write this domain in polar coordinates: I found myself this.
$$ 0 \le r \le 1$$
$$ r\ge 2sin(theta) $$
$$ r \ge -2sin(theta) $$

the integral is : $$ \iint (1-x) dxdy $$ over the domain D; my question is: how could I write a form like $$ something \le theta \le something $$
PS: I already have r, if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is symmetric respect to $x$ axis, then
\begin{align}
\iint (1-x) dxdy
&= 2\int_{y\geq0}\int (1-x) dxdy \\
&= 2\int_0^{\pi/6}\int_{2\sin\theta}^1(1-r\cos\theta)r\ dr\ d\theta+2\int_{5\pi/6}^\pi\int_{-2\sin\theta}^1(1-r\cos\theta)r\ dr\ d\theta \\
&= \color{blue}{\dfrac16+\sqrt{3}-\dfrac{\pi}{3}}
\end{align}

Comment: Could I ask why theta is equal to pi/2? (first integral and second one)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/FUBik10

Comment: It seems to be right. My bad, I have no solution.